# How to run bash command in Python script?

Tags: python, bash

I want to convert some PDF file to TXT file in a bash script.

pdf2txt.py -o otuput.txt input.pdf

this is the command to do the task for a single file.
But for large set of file I am trying to do the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/z..../P...../file/pdf

python << END

import os
file_lst = os.listdir(r'/home/z..../P...../file/pdf')

out_file_lst = []
l = len(file_lst)

for i in file_lst:
    out_file_lst.append(file_lst[0].split('.')[0] + '.txt')

for i in range(l):
    pdf2txt.py -o out_file_lst[i] file_lst[i] 
    # How to run this bash command inside of python ?

END
```

Comment: This has been answered previously.  See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415522/running-a-bash-script-from-python

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that is not I am looking for.

Comment: Why are you making this a `bash` script in the first place? You have a Python script, and the only `bash` command (`cd ...`) can be moved into the Python script anyway using `os.chdir`. Alternately, make the whole thing a `bash` script without using Python. Alternating languages like this serves no purpose.

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossan - you are specifically asking how to run a bash command from python, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415522/running-a-bash-script-from-python show you exactly how to do it - all you need to do is plugin your specific command.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a bin/bash script that convert all pdf files in your directory in txt files.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.pdf;
do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt";
done
```

Comment: except output ends up as `somefile.pdf.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) lib.

For example:

```
return_code = subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])
```