# Opening a terminal running the same program in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am familiar with how to open a terminal from Python (`os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"exec bash\"'")`), but is there a way to open another terminal running the same program that opened the new terminal?

For instance, if I was running a program called `foo.py` and it opened another terminal, the new terminal would also be running `foo.py`.

Comment: Use threads, or see if running the first string with "nohup" prepended.

Comment: Open a terminal, run this program. And that program opens another terminal, and it auto runs the same program, and again and again and again right?

Comment: @Evert can you provide me an example?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I misunderstood your question: I read it as the same program opening multiple terminals after each other.

Comment: Do you need `os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c 'exec python /path/to/foo.py'")` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415522/running-a-bash-script-from-python?rq=1), it's pretty close. You want to add sys.argv as a parameter, though:

```
import sys
import subprocess
cmd = 'xterm -hold -e ./{0}'.format(' '.join(sys.argv))
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Be sure you somehow check how many processes/terminals you run already, otherwise it will hang your machine in a matter of seconds.

Comment: I tried that but the xterm terminal outputs "bash: foo.py: command not found." Also, I am trying to do it with gnome-terminal. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I edited the answer, it's probably that it should be "./foo.py", not "foo.py". Don't know much about gnome-terminal parameters, sorry.